# Mockito with Kotlin: AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to make google's [test lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5) code example to work with kotlin. But after converting interface which I'd like to mock to kotlin I'm getting an `AbstractMethodError` which I'm unable to resolve.

**build.gradle:**

```
testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47"

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
```

**NotesPresenterTest.kt**

```
 package com.example.android.testing.notes.notes
 import org.mockito.Matchers.any

/**
 * Unit tests for the implementation of [NotesPresenter]
 */
class NotesPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private val mNotesView: NotesContract.View? = null

    @Before
    fun setupNotesPresenter() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        // Get a reference to the class under test
        mNotesPresenter = NotesPresenter(mNotesRepository!!, mNotesView!!)
    }

    @Test
    fun clickOnFab_ShowsAddsNoteUi() {
        //        // When adding a new note
        mNotesPresenter!!.addNewNote()
        //
        //        // Then add note UI is shown
        verify<NotesContract.View>(mNotesView).showAddNote()
    }

    @Test
    fun clickOnNote_ShowsDetailUi() {
        // Given a stubbed note
        val requestedNote = Note("Details Requested", "For this note")

        // When open note details is requested
        mNotesPresenter!!.openNoteDetails(requestedNote)

        // Then note detail UI is shown
        verify<NotesContract.View>(mNotesView).showNoteDetailUi(any())
    }

    companion object {

        private val NOTES = Lists.newArrayList(Note("Title1", "Description1"),
                Note("Title2", "Description2"))

        private val EMPTY_NOTES = ArrayList<Note>(0)
    }
}
```

**NotesContract.java**

```
public interface NotesContract {

interface View {

    void setProgressIndicator(boolean active);

    void showNotes(List<Note> notes);

    void showAddNote();

    void showNoteDetailUi(String noteId);
}

interface UserActionsListener {

    void loadNotes(boolean forceUpdate);

    void addNewNote();

    void openNoteDetails(@NonNull Note requestedNote);
}

}
```

Here, after converting NotesContract to kotlin I get the the next error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: any() must not be null at
>   com.example.android.testing.notes.notes.NotesPresenterTest.clickOnNote_ShowsDetailUi(NotesPresenterTest.kt:98)

So I added Mockito-Kotlin to resolve it.

```
testCompile ("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:0.9.0", {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
})
```

Which resolves previous but runs with another error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;
>
> at
>   org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
>     at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)   at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
>     at
>   org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
>     at
>   com.example.android.testing.notes.notes.NotesPresenterTest.setupNotesPresenter(NotesPresenterTest.kt:58)

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Mockito and PowerMock cannot work together well. So dependency should be either:

```
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47"
testCompile ("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:0.9.0", {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
})
```

or, if You'd like to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven) with JUnit 4.0-4.3:

```
testCompile ("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:0.9.0", {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
})

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-legacy:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
```

Comment: You would ever wanna use PowerMock? =D